# Compile FreeCAD on macOS Big Sur 11.5.1 with Homebrew, error finding XercesC files

Tags: cmake, xerces, freecad

I’m stuck compiling FC on macOS Big Sur. The build breaks with an error not finding certain XercesC libraries. But these libraries are installed and the path is even found by the CMake preparation process.

I postet this issue in the FreeCAD forum under https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=60663, but found no help. I would appreciate if anyone here at StackOverflow could verify this error or better yet have a hint for a solution. Thanks in advance.

System Info:

- macOS Big Sur version 11.5.1
- Homebrew version 3.2.5-15-g13d3eab
- FreeCAD Version from latest master, see https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD

Complete steps for the build prozess:

```sh
# install freecad dependencies via homebrew
brew tap freecad/freecad
brew install eigen
brew install --only-dependencies freecad --with-packaging-utils

# Freecad source is located in folder freecad-source/
# setup the build folder and change into newly created folder
mkdir -p freecad-build
cd freecad-build

# export path to installed dependencies
export PREFIX_PATH="\
/usr/local/opt/qt5152/lib/cmake;\
/usr/local/opt/nglib/Contents/Resources;\
/usr/local/opt/vtk@8.2.0/lib/cmake;\
/usr/local/opt/opencascade@7.5.0/lib/cmake;\
/usr/local/opt/med-file/share/cmake;\
/usr/local/opt/shiboken2/lib/cmake;\
/usr/local/opt/pyside2/lib/cmake;\
/usr/local/opt/coin@4.0.0;\
/usr/local/opt/boost@1.75.0/lib/cmake;\
/usr/local/opt/boost-python3@1.75.0/lib/cmake"

# initiate build instructions
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
  -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST \
  -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=OFF \
  -Wno-dev \
  -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF \
  -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk \
  -DBUILD_QT5=ON \
  -DUSE_PYTHON3=1 \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14 \
  -DBUILD_ENABLE_CXX_STD:STRING=C++14 \
  -DBUILD_FEM_NETGEN=1 \
  -DBUILD_FEM=1 \
  -DBUILD_FEM_NETGEN:BOOL=ON \
  -DBUILD_WEB=ON \
  -DFREECAD_USE_EXTERNAL_KDL=ON \
  -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/opt/python3.9/bin/python3 \
  -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/opt/python3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers \
  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$PREFIX_PATH" \
  -DFREECAD_CREATE_MAC_APP=1 \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./.." \
  ../freecad-source
```

The CMake process ends successfully with the following summary report. Note here, that XercesC is correctly found under
-- XercesC: 3.2.3 [/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.dylib] [/usr/local/include]:

```sh
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Compiler: AppleClang, version: 12.0.5.12050022
-- Looking for GL/gl.h
-- Looking for GL/gl.h - not found
-- Looking for C++ include istream
-- Looking for C++ include istream - found
-- Looking for C++ include ostream
-- Looking for C++ include ostream - found
-- Looking for C++ include fstream
-- Looking for C++ include fstream - found
-- Looking for C++ include sstream
-- Looking for C++ include sstream - found
-- Looking for C++ include ios
-- Looking for C++ include ios - found
-- Looking for C++ include iostream
-- Looking for C++ include iostream - found
-- Looking for C++ include iomanip
-- Looking for C++ include iomanip - found
-- Looking for C++ include iostream
-- Looking for C++ include iostream - found
-- Check for STD namespace
-- Check for STD namespace - found
-- Force BOOST_PP_VARIADICS=1 for clang
-- prefix: /Users/dirkolbrich/Freecad
-- bindir: bin
-- datadir: share
-- docdir: share/doc/FreeCAD
-- includedir: include
-- libdir: lib
-- cmake: 3.21.1
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
=====================================================
Doxygen not found, will not build documentation.
=====================================================

-- Detected Homebrew install at /usr/local
-- Found Python3: /usr/local/bin/python3.9 (found version "3.9.6") found components: Interpreter Development Development.Module Development.Embed
-- Found XercesC: /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.dylib (found version "3.2.3")
-- Found ZLIB: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11")

# lots of other setup stuff deleted for clarity
#
#

==============
Summary report
==============

-- Build type:          Release
-- Compiler:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ (12.0.5.12050022)
-- Flags:               -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-write-strings  -Wno-undefined-var-template
-- Standard:            Requires C++14
-- Python:              3.9.6 [/usr/local/bin/python3.9] [.cpython-39-darwin]
-- PCL:                 not enabled
-- pybind11:            not enabled
-- Boost:               1.75.0 (1.75.0)
-- XercesC:             3.2.3 [/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.dylib] [/usr/local/include]
-- ZLIB:                1.2.11
-- PyCXX:               6.2.8 [/Users/dirkolbrich/Freecad/freecad-source/src]
-- OCC:                 7.5.0 [TKFillet;TKMesh;TKernel;TKG2d;TKG3d;TKMath;TKIGES;TKSTL;TKShHealing;TKXSBase;TKBool;TKBO;TKBRep;TKTopAlgo;TKGeomAlgo;TKGeomBase;TKOffset;TKPrim;TKSTEPBase;TKSTEPAttr;TKSTEP209;TKSTEP;TKHLR;TKFeat] [/usr/local/opt/opencascade@7.5.0/lib] [/usr/local/opt/opencascade@7.5.0/include/opencascade]
-- SMESH:               build internal
--  MEDFile:            4.0.0 [/usr/local/lib/libmedC.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libmed.dylib] [/usr/local/include]
--  HDF5:               1.12.1
--  VTK:                8.2.0
-- NETGEN:              6.2.2101 (6.2.2101) [-DNO_PARALLEL_THREADS;-DOCCGEOMETRY;-DNETGEN_VERSION=395829] [] [/usr/local/opt/nglib/Contents/Resources/include/include;/usr/local/opt/nglib/Contents/Resources/include] [nglib] [/usr/local/opt/nglib/Contents/Resources/include/include;/usr/local/opt/nglib/Contents/Resources/include]
-- SWIG:                4.0.2
-- Eigen3               3.3.9
-- Qt5Core:             5.15.2
-- Qt5Network:          5.15.2
-- Qt5Xml:              5.15.2
-- Qt5XmlPatterns:      5.15.2
-- Qt5Widgets:          5.15.2
-- Qt5PrintSupport:     5.15.2
-- Qt5OpenGL:           5.15.2
-- Qt5Svg:              5.15.2
-- Qt5UiTools:          5.15.2
-- Qt5Concurrent:       5.15.2
-- Qt5WebEngineWidgets: 5.15.2
-- Shiboken2:           5.15.2 [/usr/local/opt/shiboken2/lib/cmake/Shiboken2-5.15.2] [/usr/local/opt/shiboken2/include/shiboken2;/usr/local/opt/python3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers]
-- PySide2:             5.15.2 [/usr/local/opt/pyside2/include/PySide2]
-- PySide2Tools:        [/usr/local/bin/uic] [/usr/local/bin/rcc]
-- Freetype:            2.11.0
-- OpenGL:              /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework
-- OpenGLU:             [/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework][/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework]
-- Coin3D:              4.0.0 [/usr/local/opt/coin@4.0.0/lib/libCoin.dylib] [/usr/local/opt/coin@4.0.0/include]
-- Pivy:                0.6.5
-- SPNAV:               [SPNAV_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND] [SPNAV_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND]
-- Matplotlib:          2.1.1
-- Rift:                not enabled (BUILD_VR)
-- Doxygen:             not found
=================================================
Now run 'cmake --build /Users/dirkolbrich/Freecad/freecad-build' to build FreeCAD
=================================================

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/dirkolbrich/Freecad/freecad-build
```

Now I start the build process with the following steps:

```sh
# set path to icu4c
# see https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?p=507588#p507588
export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"

#start the build according to the last line of the cmake summary report
cmake --build /Users/dirkolbrich/freecad/freecad-build/release
```

The build errors shortly before finish with an error of not finding the XercesC library files:

```sh
[ 91%] Building CXX object src/Mod/Measure/App/CMakeFiles/Measure.dir/AppMeasure.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/dirkolbrich/freecad/freecad-source/src/Mod/Measure/App/AppMeasure.cpp:32:
In file included from /Users/dirkolbrich/freecad/freecad-source/src/Mod/Measure/App/Measurement.h:29:
In file included from /Users/dirkolbrich/freecad/freecad-source/src/App/DocumentObject.h:28:
In file included from /Users/dirkolbrich/freecad/freecad-source/src/App/TransactionalObject.h:27:
In file included from /Users/dirkolbrich/freecad/freecad-source/src/App/ExtensionContainer.h:33:
/Users/dirkolbrich/freecad/freecad-source/src/Base/Reader.h:32:10: fatal error: 'xercesc/framework/XMLPScanToken.hpp' file not found
#include <xercesc/framework/XMLPScanToken.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/Mod/Measure/App/CMakeFiles/Measure.dir/AppMeasure.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/Mod/Measure/App/CMakeFiles/Measure.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The not found files exist under the specified path at `/usr/local/include/xercesc/framework/XMLPScanToken.hpp` according to the summary report and verified manually.

Even adding `-DXERCESC_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/xercesc` to the cmake command does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the build script.
The [final report](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/blob/5d49bf78de785a536f941f1a6d06d432582a95d3/cMake/FreeCAD_Helpers/PrintFinalReport.cmake#L32) prints `XercesC_INCLUDE_DIRS`,
but the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/blob/5d49bf78de785a536f941f1a6d06d432582a95d3/src/Mod/Measure/App/CMakeLists.txt#L16) for that subdirectory uses `XERCESC_INCLUDE_DIR`.

I suggest you fix the typo (to `XercesC_INCLUDE_DIRS`) in `src/Mod/Measure/App/CMakeLists.txt` and file a pull request.

Comment: Thanks, good hint. But unfortunately no success. I changed `src/Mod/Measure/App/CMakeLists.txt` to use `XercesC_INCLUDE_DIRS` in my local build repo, reset the build folder and build from scratch. The error still persists. I think `XercesC_INCLUDE_DIR` is a cache variable derived from `XercesC_INCLUDE_DIRS` according to the Xerces docs https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindXercesC.html

Comment: Within `src/Base/CMakeList.txt` the variable `XercesC_INCLUDE_DIRS` is already used, as the actual error occurs in [`src/Base/Reader.h:32:10:`](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/blob/d635f03a60a7ae1e6f9d390b9cbd7bdb91692996/src/Base/Reader.h#L32).

Comment: I have to apologize. Your solution worked. On the first try I used `XERCESC_INCLUDE_DIRS` with all capital letters. On the second try I used `XercesC_INCLUDE_DIRS` with capital and lower letters, now the build succeeds.

Comment: Don't forget to create a pull request / issue! (and link back to this question)